# running if and else within a for loop across columns

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, apply

I am attempting to have R read across columns by row and evaluate whether values from two adjacent cells are equal. If the values are equal, I want R to count this occurence in a new variable. Here is example data (df):

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

...and I want to get here:

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | NewVar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

One example set of code I have tried out is the following:

```
df$NewVar <- 0

for (i in 1:2){
  if (df[i]==df[i+1]){
    df$NewVar <- df$NewVar + 1
  }
  else{
    df$NewVar <- df$NewVar
  }
}
```

This particular set of code just returns 0s in the NewVar variable.

Any sort of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Both of you should learn that df[1]  and df[,1] are the same.

Comment: @DavidB.  The if-function cannot handle columns. And your code would not be applying a row-based test and calculation. Look instead at ifelse().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution using `rowSums` :

```
df$NewVar <- rowSums(df[-1] == df[-ncol(df)])
df

#  Var1 Var2 Var3 NewVar
#1    2    3    3      1
#2    3    3    3      2
#3    1    2    3      0
#4    3    2    1      0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), Var2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L), Var3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Reduce`

```
df$NewVar <- Reduce(`+`, Map(`==`, df[-1], df[-ncol(df)]))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), Var2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L), Var3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```